# NullPointerException, хотя путь указан правильно

Tags: java

Вот конструктор:

```
private String fileCheckPresenceBuildMods;
private static Scanner scn;
private int numberTxtFile=1;

public ControllerMainMenu(){
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
        fileCheckPresenceBuildMods = "/StorageVariablesFolder/PresenceBuildMods/"+ numberTxtFile +".txt";
        System.out.println(fileCheckPresenceBuildMods);
        getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileCheckPresenceBuildMods);
        try{
            scn=new Scanner(new File(fileCheckPresenceBuildMods));
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println(" *Ошибка!"); System.err.println("");}

        while(scn.hasNext()){
            booleanBuildsMods[i] =scn.nextBoolean();
        }
        scn.close();

        numberTxtFile++;
    }
}
```

Посмотрел путь к txt файлам. Вот:
D:\Workspace\Assistant\src\sample\StorageVariablesFolder\PresenceBuildMods\1.txt

Ошибка:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Workspace/Assistant/out/production/Assistant/sample/MainChoiceTheBuildMenu.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:36)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.ControllerMainMenu.<init>(ControllerMainMenu.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

В консоль выводит fileCheckPresenceBuildMods:

```
/StorageVariablesFolder/PresenceBuildMods/1.txt
```

Если писать такой путь, он работает, но тогда я не смогу создать файл jar без ошибок.

```
src//sample//StorageVariablesFolder//PresenceBuildMods//1.txt
```

Я изначально писал программу с таким путем:

```
src\\sample\\StorageVariablesFolder\\PresenceBuildMods\\"+ numberTxtFile +".txt
```

Но тогда при запуске jar файл выдает NPE, хотя в eclipse все работает. Нашел решение проблемы на одном форуме:

```
String path = "resources/yourImage.png";
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

И в другом методе моей программы такая штука прокатила, а здесь нет(

Почему выдает ошибку?
Заранее спасибо всем)

Comment: Вот вы дали кусок кода и сказали что где-то в нем NPE, но не дали трассу стека, вот как это назвать? :) Проверьте значение `scn`, похоже оно не инициализировано. Плюс, выведите в консоль переменную `fileCheckPresenceBuildMods ` и проверьте что путь и ее значение совпадает. Попробуйте привести полный путь к файлу.

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь

Comment: А в чем проблема с созданием jar'ника?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать путь следующим образом:

```
fileCheckPresenceBuildMods = "src\\sample\\StorageVariablesFolder\\PresenceBuildMods\\"+ numberTxtFile +".txt";
```